# Differentiation of an inclination function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function. Define $F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$F(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} & x\neq y \\
f'(x) & x=y
 \end{cases} $$

It's very easy to prove that there exists $Df(x,y)$ if $x \neq y$, however I used a very long argument to prove $Df(x,x)$ also exists, which included writing

$$\frac{f(x + t) - f(x)}{t} = \int_{0}^1 f'(x+st) \mathrm{ds}$$

And using $f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x-x_0) + r(x)(x-x_0)$.

I am not satisfied with this solution. Can someone provide-me with a simpler and more direct proof?

Comment: Can anyone suggest improvements or corrections to this?